# Scheduling Optimization for multi-step growth modeling

Tags: mysql, optimization, scheduling, pyomo

I recently had a Gaussian Process machine learning program built for my production department. This GP system has built a massive mySQL database that provides growth durations for each of the organisms we grow (Lab environment) and the predicted yield for each of those combinations of growth steps.

I would like to build an optimization program in python (preferably) to assist me in scheduling what organisms to grow, when to grow them, and for how long at each step.

Here is some background:

- 4 steps to the process

  1. Plate step (organism is plated; growth is started)
  2. Seed step (organism transferred from plate to seed phase)
  3. Incubation step (organism is transferred from seed to incubation phase)
  4. Harvest step (organism is harvested; yield collected)
- There are multiple organisms (>50) that are grown per year. Each has their own numerical ID
- There is finite space to grow organisms at the incubation step
- There is infinite space to grow organisms at the plate and seed step.
- Multiple 'lots' of the same organism are typically grown at a time. A lot is predefined by the number of containers being used at the incubation step.
- Different organisms have very different maximum yields. Some yield 2000 grams max and others 600 g max.
- The mySQL server has every combination of # of days at each step for each organism and the predicted yield for that combination. This data is what needs to be used for optimization.

The massive challenge we run into is scheduling what organisms to grow when. With the GP process, we know the theoretical maximums (and they work!) but its hard putting it into practice due to constraints (see below)

Here would be my constraints:

- Only one organism can be harvested per day.
- No steps can be started on weekends. Organisms can grow over the weekend, but we can't start a new step on a weekend
- If multiple 'lots' are being grown of the same mold, the plate and seed start dates should be the same for every 'lot'.
  - What this typically looks like in practice is:
  - plate and seed steps start on the same day
  - next, incubation steps start day-after-day for as many lots as being made
  - finally, harvests occur in the same pattern (day-after-day)
  - Therefore, what you typically get is identical # of days in the plate phase, identical # of incubation days, and differing # of seed days.

Objective Function: I don't know how to articulate this perfectly, but very broadly we need to maximize the yields for each organism. However, there needs to be a time balance too as the space to grow the organisms is finite and the time we have to grow them is finite as well.

I have created a metric known as lot*weeks that tries to capture that. It is a measure of the number of the number of weeks (at the incubation phase) needed to grow the expected annual demand of a specific organism based upon the predicted yield from the SQL server. Therefore, a potential objective function would be to minimize the lot_weeks for each organism.

This is obviously more of a broad ask for help. I don't have a specific request. If this is not appropriate for this forum, I can take my question elsewhere. I feel comfortable with the scope of the project and can figure out how to write the code over time but I need assistance with what tools to use and what's possible.

I've seen that pyomo may be helpful but I also wanted to check here first. Thank you

I've tried looking into using Pyomo but stopped due to the complexity and didn't want to learn all of it if it wasn't appropriate for the problem.

Edit: This was too broad, I apologize. I've created another post with more concrete examples. Thank you for all that helped.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A database is a persistent repository for data; it is not a logic engine.  Look for a tag relating to modeling or algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

This is really too broad of a question for this forum, and it may likely get closed.  That said...

You have a framework here that you could develop an optimization in.  The database part is irrelevant.  For an effective optimization model, what you really need is a known relationship between the variables and the outcomes, for instance, days in incubation ==> size of harvest or such.  Which it sounds like you have.

This isn't an entry level model you are describing.  Do you have any resources to help?  Local university that might have need for grad student projects in the field or such?

As you develop this, you should start small and focus the model on the key issues here...  if they aren't known, then perhaps that is the place to start.  For instance, perhaps the key issue is management of planting times vis-a-vis the weekends (that is one model).  Or perhaps the key issue is the management of the limited space for growth and the inability to achieve steps on the weekend just kinda works itself out.  (That is another model for space management.)  Try one that seems to address key management questions.  Start very small and see if you can get something working as a proof of concept.  If this is your first foray into linear programming, you will need help.  You might also start with an introductory textbook on LP.